# Query to get most expensive book per author

Tags: sql, oracle

How to write a sql query in Oracle to get results for:

Table "books" has five columns: BOOK_ID,
                                BOOK_TITLE,
                                BOOK_AUTHOR,
                                PRICE,
                                PUBLISH_DATE. 
Print list of most expensive book per author published during last 300 days ?

```
select book_author, 
       publish_date 
  from books 
 where max(price) and publish_date between (sysdate-300) and sysdate;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do accomplish your goal. This is a self-exclusion join and should be fairly efficient. It basically says return me the row(s) with a price for which there is no higher price; for each author. There is a tested example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/86b22/1

```
select 
    b.book_author, b.publish_date, b.price
from 
    books b
    left join books b2
    on b.book_author = b2.book_author
    and b2.price > b.price
    and b2.publish_date between (sysdate-300) and sysdate
where 
    b.publish_date between (sysdate-300) and sysdate
    and b2.book_id is null;
```

In case you are interested, more examples of this type of query can be found on my blog: http://adam-bernier.appspot.com/post/38001/the-self-exclusion-join

Comment: I have only one table (books). Do I have to create a second table? Thank you for your response.

Comment: @YoyoMe Books is the only table.  Bernie is just referencing it twice.  Notice the alias of `b` and `b2`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [analytics](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#i81407) to accomplish this as well:

```
select * 
  from (select book_id,
               book_author,
               price,
               publish_date,
               row_number() over (partition by book_author order by price desc) rn
          from books
         where publish_date >= (sysdate - 300)
       )
 where rn = 1;
```

Comment: you'd want rank vs row_number to cater for two or more books having top price.

Comment: Hi Dominic, yes I would like to get 2 or 3 books with the top price.  How do I get that?

Comment: @YoyoMe  Instead of `row_number()` you would use `rank()`.  That would show you multiple books by the same author if they had the same price.